# Watir-Webdriver: How to click on an element location?

Tags: watir-webdriver

We have a custom input element that contains several div elements that are masked behind a canvas element.  The div elements handle click events, and this works fine in all browsers.

How can we click such an element in Watir-Webdriver?  If we locate the div element and use the .click method, it causes the error:

```
Element is not clickable at point (423, 247). Other element would receive the click: <canvas></canvas>
```

Which of course it would, before event bubbling.  What we want to do is to click the location where the div element is (which first clicks the canvas, and then bubbles to the div).

We wouldn't want to fire JavaScript events directly to the div, as it does not correctly test the event bubbling.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the page (or control)? I think you can use the underlying selenium-webdriver to get the location of the div and then click the canvas at a specific location. However, it is hard to verify if it works without a test page.

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, just click the canvas element just like you clicked the div. But to answer the question you raised: you can try to access the underlying selenium-webdriver browser driver and utilize selenium-webdriver methods to do this.

```
    driver = $browser.driver
    element = driver.find_element(css:'div.class_name')
    driver.action.move_to(element).click.perform
```